# passing values from jframe to another

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

i have two jframes and a want to pass values from jpanel from the first jframe to a sql query in the scond jframe.

```
package gestioner;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Customers extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JLabel lblFullName;
private JTextField funame;
private JLabel lblEmail;
private JTextField email;
private JLabel lblAdresse;
private JTextField adresse;
private JLabel lblTel;
private JTextField tel;
private JButton button;
private JButton button_1;
private JButton button_2;
private JButton btnShowAll;
private JLabel label_4;
private JTextField search;
private JTable table;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Customers frame = new Customers();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
public JLabel id;
private JButton btnSales;

public String getLab() {
    // String z =funame.getText();
    return funame.getText();
}

public void fillTable() {

    try {
        String query = "select * from customers";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        // center allignment
        ((DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer())
                .setHorizontalAlignment((int) JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
        for (int x = 0; x < table.getColumnCount(); x++) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    }

}

public Customers() {

    con = Connectdb.connect();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 867, 492);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    lblFullName = new JLabel("Full Name");
    lblFullName.setBounds(20, 92, 78, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblFullName);

    funame = new JTextField();
    funame.setColumns(10);
    funame.setBounds(116, 89, 125, 20);
    contentPane.add(funame);

    lblEmail = new JLabel("Email");
    lblEmail.setBounds(20, 120, 78, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEmail);

    email = new JTextField();
    email.setColumns(10);
    email.setBounds(116, 117, 125, 20);
    contentPane.add(email);

    lblAdresse = new JLabel("Adresse");
    lblAdresse.setBounds(20, 148, 78, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblAdresse);

    adresse = new JTextField();
    adresse.setColumns(10);
    adresse.setBounds(116, 145, 125, 20);
    contentPane.add(adresse);

    lblTel = new JLabel("Tel");
    lblTel.setBounds(20, 176, 78, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblTel);

    tel = new JTextField();
    tel.setColumns(10);
    tel.setBounds(116, 173, 125, 20);
    contentPane.add(tel);

    button = new JButton("Add");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                String query = "Insert into customers (fullname,email,adress,tele) values (?,?,?,?)";
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1, funame.getText());
                pst.setString(2, email.getText());
                pst.setString(3, adresse.getText());
                pst.setString(4, tel.getText());
                pst.execute();
                fillTable();
                funame.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                adresse.setText("");
                tel.setText("");
                id.setText("");

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    button.setBounds(20, 213, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(button);

    button_1 = new JButton("Edit");
    button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                String query = "update customers set fullname= '" + funame.getText() + "' , email= '"
                        + email.getText() + "' , adress= '" + adresse.getText() + "', tele= '" + tel.getText()
                        + "' where id= '" + id.getText() + "'  ";
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

                // pst.setString(1, funame.getText());
                // pst.setString(2, email.getText());
                // pst.setString(3, adresse.getText());
                // pst.setString(4, tel.getText());
                pst.execute();
                fillTable();

                funame.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                adresse.setText("");
                tel.setText("");
                id.setText("");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    button_1.setBounds(152, 213, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(button_1);

    button_2 = new JButton("Delete");
    button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                String query = "delete from customers where id='" + id.getText() + "'";
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.execute();
                fillTable();
                funame.setText("");
                adresse.setText("");
                tel.setText("");
                email.setText("");
                id.setText("");

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    button_2.setBounds(20, 247, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(button_2);

    btnShowAll = new JButton("Show All");
    btnShowAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                String query = "select * from customers";
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                ((DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer())
                        .setHorizontalAlignment((int) JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
                for (int x = 0; x < table.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
                }

                pst.close();
                rs.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

            }

        }
    });
    btnShowAll.setBounds(733, 386, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnShowAll);

    label_4 = new JLabel("Search");
    label_4.setBounds(647, 35, 61, 14);
    contentPane.add(label_4);

    search = new JTextField();
    search.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

            try {

                if (search.getText().equals("")) {
                    fillTable();
                } else {
                    String query = "select * from customers where id like ? or fullname like ? or tele like ? ";
                    pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    pst.setString(1, search.getText() + "%");
                    pst.setString(2, search.getText() + "%");
                    pst.setString(3, search.getText() + "%");
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    search.setColumns(10);
    search.setBounds(699, 32, 123, 20);
    contentPane.add(search);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(271, 62, 551, 309);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            try {

                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                String table_click = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
                String query = "select * from customers where id= '" + table_click + "'";
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                if (rs.next()) {
                    String add1 = rs.getString("id");
                    id.setText(add1);
                    String add2 = rs.getString("fullname");
                    funame.setText(add2);
                    String add3 = rs.getString("email");
                    email.setText(add3);
                    String add4 = rs.getString("adress");
                    adresse.setText(add4);
                    String add5 = rs.getString("tele");
                    tel.setText(add5);

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    id = new JLabel("");
    id.setBounds(116, 64, 125, 14);
    contentPane.add(id);

    btnSales = new JButton("Sales");
    btnSales.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            new Showsales().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
    btnSales.setBounds(152, 247, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnSales);
}

}
```

the second jframe

```
package gestioner;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Showsales extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable table;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JButton btnShowAll;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Showsales frame = new Showsales();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
private JLabel lblSearch;
private JTextField search;

public void fillTable() {

    try {

        String query = "select * from sales where customerid=";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        ((DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer())
                .setHorizontalAlignment((int) JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
        for (int x = 0; x < table.getColumnCount(); x++) {
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
        }

        pst.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

    }

}

public Showsales() {

    con = Connectdb.connect();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 868, 495);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(232, 40, 610, 363);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    btnShowAll = new JButton("Show All");
    btnShowAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {

                String query = "select * from sales";
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                ((DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer())
                        .setHorizontalAlignment((int) JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
                for (int x = 0; x < table.getColumnCount(); x++) {
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
                }

                pst.close();
                rs.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

            }

        }
    });
    btnShowAll.setBounds(717, 423, 125, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnShowAll);

    lblSearch = new JLabel("Search");
    lblSearch.setBounds(609, 15, 65, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblSearch);

    search = new JTextField();
    search.setBounds(684, 12, 158, 20);
    contentPane.add(search);
    search.setColumns(10);
}

}
```

so i want when the user click the button sales, we take the value of id label and put it in a sql query in the second jframe :

```
String = "select * from sales where cusotmerid='"+id+"'";
```

and execute it and show the table automatically when click the button sales.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have two applications? I see two main functions in your sample code, so do you want to pass a value from first jframe in first app to second jframe in other?
If you just want to pass a value from a jframe to other in a application, you can do this way:

```
 class Frame1 extends JFrame {
    private JLabel idLabel;
    public Frame1() {
        .........
        gotoSecondFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int id = Integer.parseInt(idLabel.getText());// just get id value from jlabel
                JFrame2 frame = new JFram2(id);// then pass to second jframe
                frame.setVisible(true);// show second jframe
            }
        });
        ........
    }
}

class Frame2 extends JFrame {
    private void query(int id) {
        .......
    }
    public Frame2(int id) {
        .......
        query(id);// your query with id which passed from first jframe
        .......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value from FirstJFrame to SecondJFrame using SecondJFrame's constructor

FirstJFrame.java

```
public class FirstJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JButton btn = new JButton("Send Value");

    public FirstJFrame() {

         getContentPane().add(btn);

    }
    private void btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        SecondJFrame secondFrame = new SecondJFrame(13);
// 13 is the value 

       secondFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

SecondJFrame.java

```
public class SecondJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    int id = 0;

    public SecondJFrame (int idValue) {

          int id = idValue;

          System.out.println(id);
    }

}
```